# Get Text in Span Using CSS Selector

Tags: html, css

I'm using a product called Stonly to place tool tips.  In there, we are to use the CSS Selector to find the HTML element to identify the tool tip.  Now, when I do this for some of our elements on the page, the path isn't what I always want.  Instead, I want to identify the element to place a tool tip based on the text in the span.  How would I do that?

Below is the CSS Selector output

```
#root > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.container > div > div.w70.w-990-100 > div:nth-child(3) > div > form > h4 > span
```

Below is the snippent of HTML

```
<div className="comm-section">
            <form autoComplete="off">
                <h4 className="commHdn"><span> Type of Property {data?.type_of_property_id} </span></h4>
                {/* 17Dec */}
                <div className="f-row f-3 f-576-2">
                    {/* start */}
```

Comment: this might be alittle difficult with using css selectors I believe. If you can somehow add `data-` attribute and do comparison there it might be possible.

Comment: ok. I ended up adding a data attribute (target) on the span and was able to locate it.  problem solved!

eg

#root > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.container > div > div.w70.w-990-100 > div.animated.fadeIn > div > form > h4 > span[target=CO1]

Comment: @Homsby feel free to post this as an answer or close the issue. thx.